# I have to load json data, which is available on other domain, How I will do that

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain

I have to load json data, which is available on the **other domain**, How I will do, The formate of Json data is

```
[
            {
                "siteName": "JQUERY4U",
                "domainName": "http://www.jquery4u.com",
                "description": "#1 jQuery Blog for your Daily News, Plugins, Tuts/Tips &amp; Code Snippets."
            },
            {
                "siteName": "BLOGOOLA",
                "domainName": "http://www.blogoola.com",
                "description": "Expose your blog to millions and increase your audience."
            },
            {
                "siteName": "PHPSCRIPTS4U",
                "domainName": "http://www.phpscripts4u.com",
                "description": "The Blog of Enthusiastic PHP Scripters"
            }
]
```

I want to just read json file through Jquery, how I will do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use jsonp as datatype in $.ajax()  method of Jquery or $.getJSON with call back

**using  $.ajax**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: your_link,
            dataType: "jsonp", 
            success: function(data){
               //do something here                      
                }
            }
            error : function(data){
                      console.log(data);
                     }
        });
```

**using $.getJSON**

To trigger a JSONP request you need to add callback_name=? string at the end of the URL.

```
$.getJSON( "https://your_domain.com?callback=?", function( data ){
  console.log( data.title ); // log data here
});
```